# Equation in the Gaussian Integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. Is there a possibility to characterize the solutions of $a N(\alpha) - b N(\beta)=1$ where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$? In particular I am interested in the case $a=1$ and $b=p \in \mathbb{P}$ with $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$.

Comment: Is $\ N(x+i\cdot y) := x^2+y^2\ $ or are there some other "suggestions"?